# What's the best way to inject bound HTML in Polymer 2

Tags: polymer-2.x

I need to display some bound HTML in my app.

In Polymer <0.8 there was injectBoundHTML, in 1 there was Polymer.Templatizer, but what is the best way in Polymer 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Polymer 2 also, you can use `Polymer.Templatizer`.

Documentation can be found here: https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/api/namespaces/Polymer.Templatize.
There are few changes on code.